# Async не ожидать результата

Tags: c#

Выполняю асинхронную работу. Где-то ожидаю результата, где-то нет. И в местах, где не ожидаю (по типу `Update(notice);`) студия мне подчёркивает зелёным эту строку, как я понял, намекая на то, что я делаю не правильно.

В таком случае возникает вопрос: как правильно не ожидать выполнения метода, при работе с async await?

```
public void chatNoticeNew(ChatMessageArgs chatMessage) {
    ...
    Update(notice); //ждать не нужно
    ...
}

private async Task Update(ChatNotice notice) {
    ...
    notice.Blink(100, 100, 2); //ждать не нужно
    if (await notice.WaitAndVanishing(20000)) { //ждать нужно, приходит Task<bool>
        ...
    }
}
public async Task Blink(int on, int off, int n) {
    ...
    await Task.Delay(on);
    ...
    await Task.Delay(off);
}
```

Comment: Студия не может знать, хотите вы ожидать окончание метода или нет, потому она по умолчанию всегда предлагает ожидать. Если вам ожидать не надо - не ожидайте

Comment: Что бы убрать предупреждения компилятора, сохраните возвращаемую задачу в какой-нибудь переменной, например Task t = Update(notice); //ждать не нужно

Comment: @swd, тогда уж лучше с помощью `#pragma` пометить. Вы же просто маскируете одну "проблему" оставляя другую – "переменная присваивается, но нигде не используется"

Comment: @АндрейNOP В данном случае (с переменной) компилятор не будет ругаться на то, что переменная нигде не используется. Правда читать такой код не очень удобно будет. Наверное лучший вариант - сделать расширенный метод, который ставит в продолжение задачи логгирование исключений. public static void Forget(this Task task)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(
            t => { WriteLog(t.Exception); },
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }

Comment: @swd, в текущей версии не будет, но они всегда могут добавить такой warning (и это было бы логично)